# Add Library and Headers in Xcode workspace

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Workspace which has one project and I have added a static Library to that project.

WorkSpace

- MainProject
- A Static Library (ex: myLib.a).

Folder structure is as follows

Main Folder

- .xcworkspace
- MainProject -> .xcodeproj
- MyStaticLibrary-> .xcodeproj

I have added myLib.a to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".
The build settings are "OTHER_LDFlags"="-all_load" , "ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS" = NO.

But, how do I add header files?

Comment: You add them to your Xcode project like all other files, or you modify the compiler flags to tell the compiler where to find them.

Comment: "modify the compiler flags to tell the compiler where to find them" This is the option which I am trying to find. So, If I add another "MainProject", where I just want the same staticLibrary to be used, I will just have the path added. But, which setting to use.

Comment: are you used prefixheader file

Comment: Yes. In MainProject.pch , I have added MyUtillities.h . I see in build products the library is there with /include/<and all my header files>. But, Xcode settings shows only Debug-iphoneOS, it should also show Debug-iphonesimulator.